# Numerical Analysis Gauss-Lobatto

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to find the expression of the weights and nodes for the Gauss-Lobatto quadratures with 4 nodes.

I am guessing this is a sum of weights? Does anyone here have experience working with this type of math?

Comment: Hi Ian, welcome to Math StackExchange. While it's not unlikely that  someone will come along who knows very precisely what you're asking about, you'll improve your chances of getting a good answer by editing your question to include more details about the material you're studying.

Comment: [look for Lobatto here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature)

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LobattoQuadrature.html):

Nodes: $x_1 = -1, x_2 = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, x_3 = - x_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, x_4 = -x_1 = 1$

Weights:
$ w_1 = \frac{5}{6} = w_4, w_2 = \frac{1}{6} = w_3$.